# Unable to Replace Variable in Elementor Page Content

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a variable {content1} in my Elementor page content, and I am attempting to replace {content1} with 'sample text', but it's not working. Could anyone provide insight or solutions on how to successfully replace the text?

Here is what I have tried so far (include any code or methods you have used to attempt to solve the problem).

```
function create_gmt_post(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    // Get the post object.
    $new_title = $request->get_param('title');
    $post_id = 710;
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    
    if (!$post) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_post', 'Invalid Post ID', array('status' => 400));
    }
global $wpdb;
    // Create a copy of the post object and remove some of the elements.
    $copy = array(
        'post_author'    => $post->post_author,
        'post_content'   => $post->post_content,
        'post_status'    => 'draft', // Set the post status of the new post to 'draft'.
        'post_title'     => $new_title,
        'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
    );
    if (strpos($post->post_content, '{content1}') === false) {
        return new WP_Error('handle_error', 'placeholder not found in original post content', array('status' => 500));
    
}
$placeholder_position = strpos($post->post_content, '{content1}');
    //error_log('Placeholder position: ' . $placeholder_position);
    
    $new_content = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";
    $copy['post_content'] = str_replace('{content1}', $new_content, $copy['post_content']);

   
    
        
    // Insert the post into the database.
    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($copy);

    // If you want to copy the post meta information too.
    if ($new_post_id) {
        $post_meta_infos = get_post_meta($post_id);
        if (count($post_meta_infos) != 0) {
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) ";
            foreach ($post_meta_infos as $meta_key => $meta_values) {
                foreach ($meta_values as $meta_value) {
                    $meta_value = addslashes($meta_value);
                    $sql_query_sel[] = "SELECT $new_post_id, '$meta_key', '$meta_value'";
                }
            }
            $sql_query .= implode(" UNION ALL ", $sql_query_sel);
            $wpdb->query($sql_query);
             return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'post_id' => $new_post_id,
            'edit_url' => "https://www.lhg.au/wp-admin/post.php?post=".$new_post_id."&action=elementor",
            'post_url' => get_permalink($new_post_id),
        ), 200);
        }
    }
    else {
            return new WP_Error('create_post_error', 'Unable to create post', array('status' => 500));
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Waiting for your help!